# How these inner function parameters are getting a value?

Tags: javascript, parameters

I saw that function and tried to understand it, but I don't get what are the (a, i) arguments of that function. How they're getting a value assigned to them?

```
function ftRotations() {
    let str = 'abc';
    let arr = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    return arr.map(function (a,i) {
        return str.slice(i)+str.slice(0,i)
    });
}
```

Comment: Please search for the function documentation before posting: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method provides arguments when calling the callback, which are received by the callback in the `a` and `i` parameters it declares. (The callback doesn't use `a` for anything, but uses `i`. The callback also uses `str`, which it closes over because the function was created in a context where `str` exists.)

It may help to see a **rough** idea of what `map` does internally:

```
// Note: VERY ROUGH approximation, leaving out all kinds of details (like `thisArg`)
map(callback) {
    // Note: `this` is the array you called `map` on
    const result = [];
    for (let index = 0; index< this.length; ++index) {
        result[index] = callback(this[index], index, this);
        // In the callback,      ^^^^^^^^^^^  ^^^^^
        // becomes `a` −−−−−−−−−−−−−−/           \−−−−−−−becomes `i`
    }
    return result;
}
```